# How to get video and audio file in ios app with google drive

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have some video and audio file in my google drive and now i have integrate goolge drive sdk in my application.

I want to get that video and audio file form google drive and show it in ios application

How can i do this

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised you asked this question here instead of looking at [Google Drive iOS SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource).

According to this use [this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to list all files in a users Google Drive -

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

There are plenty of other API's to list the files metadata without actually downloading the file etc. Hoep this points you in the right direction. Their documentation is extensive, check it out...

Comment: Additionally our iOS quickstart is also a good entry point: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios

Comment: can u give one line code of how to make HTTP request and Authorized token tom access google drive file using downloadUrl..please