# Downloading audio file from google drive and playing

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api

I have uploaded audio from my app into google drive.Now I want to download the audio file and also play the audio while it is getting downloaded into application.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314461/how-to-get-video-and-audio-file-in-ios-app-with-google-drive

Comment: are u able to play from google drive. plz let me know.. i want to play files from google drive but not able to fetch the url...can u tell me how to resolve it

Answer (score -1):

1. Query [File.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) with restriction on filetype
2. Find webContentLink from [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource). You'll get HTTP link for file
3. There are many libraries to stream audio/video with HTTP in iOS

If you are new to Drive API, check [iOS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios)

Comment: Does it mean that without downloading audio I can just play audio using webContentLink

Comment: There is an working app called bubbleupnp which already implemented live stream of audio & video file from Drive